# Trying to calculate angle of a pie chart slice created in svg and javascript

Tags: javascript, math, svg, pie-chart

I am creating dynamic pie chart slices via javascript and svg.  I need both sides of the slice to have a border.  I can't work out the math todo this on both borders (I can get it on the starting border, but not the final end border of the slice.

```
let size = 200
let slicePercentage = 33
let radius = size / 2
let circumference = Math.PI * radius * 2
let slice = ((slicePercentage / 2) * circumference) / 100 + ' ' + circumference

let line = ((size / 2) + radius) * Math.cos(slicePercentage)
```

I have included code here to show:
https://jsfiddle.net/yg210erv/1/

Comment: if you consider 360degs = 100% and you need to know the angle for 33% you do: 33*360/100 = 118.8degs, However if you work with JavaScript you may need the angle in radians. So keep in mind that 360degs = 2*Math.PI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked the fiddle to answer your question [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lhx78zo/), but you may also want to check on the geometry of what you want to accomplish. Basically, you had `size` as the `y` coordinate of the second line, which makes no sense. I set two variables, `linex` and `liney` for the `x` and `y` coordinates of `line2`. The expressions are pretty simple:

```
let finalAngle = 2 * Math.PI * (slicePercentage/100)
let linex = radius + (radius * Math.cos(finalAngle))
let liney = radius + (radius * Math.sin(finalAngle))
```

You could also write:

```
let linex = radius * (1 + Math.cos(finalAngle))
```

But that would only work if you are going to *always* create the slices with the same center at `size/2`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes much more sense now I see the answer.  Really appreciate it.  Yes the center position will always be the same, so the solution works for everything.

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept the answer if it was useful.